# Is array.slice enough to handle a multidimensional Array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is `array.slice` enough to clone a multidimensional Array in JavaScript?

For example:

```
 var array = [
                [1, 2, 3],
                [4, 5, 6],
                [7, 8, 9]
    ];

 var b = array.slice();
 console.log(b);
```

I saw a secondary implementation as this from Play by Play: Lea Verou on pluralsight:

```
 b =  array.slice().map( function(row){ return row.slice(); });
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Clone an array of arrays.

Comment: are you always having just Numbers? if so, there's an easy way to cheat...

Comment: forget tricks, just use  array.map(function(a){return a.slice(0);}); or the slow-but-sure JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));

Comment: I found the JSON method to be faster than map method for my 9x9 array (of nulls/integers).  I know that's not saying much, but perfect for Suduko.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) are pretty clear:

> The `slice()` method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object.

So the answer is no: `slice` by itself is not enough to clone a multidimensional array. It will only clone one dimension. You need to recursively clone each element (the way the "secondary implementation" you posted is doing) if you want a deep clone.

Comment: when i did console.log(b) on both implementations, it seemed to return the same output. that's why i was confused.

Comment: @runners3431 - Using console logging to test whether one object is a clone of another is dubious; after all, if they're clones, they _should_ produce the same output. Much better would be to log the result of an identity test (e.g., `console.log(array[0] === b[0]);`). Incidentally, in the "secondary implementation", `b = array.slice().map(...)` can be replaced by `b = array.map(...)`; the `map()` function is returning a new array anyway, so making a shallow copy of `array` doesn't buy anything.

Comment: if one is a shallow clone copy, than wouldn't that not include some parts of the array?

Comment: @runners3431 - Sorry, I don't understand your last comment. Can you rephrase and/or elaborate? A shallow clone copy will contain all the same elements (identically--not clones/copies) as the original array, just in a new array object.

Answer (score 5):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

> The `slice()` method returns a **shallow** copy of a portion of an array into a new array object.

That is, it will not clone the internal arrays / objects. Observe:

```
 var array = [
                [1, 2, 3],
                [4, 5, 6],
                [7, 8, 9]
    ];

 var b = array.slice();
 b[0].push(10); 
 console.log(array);
 > [ [1, 2, 3, 10], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ]
```

So if you want a deep copy of your 2D array, then you'd have to go with the map method (or something similar).